# Using NOOBS, no keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, composite-video, noobs

I have a keyboard/mouse combo that connect via Bluetooth to a sensor that plugs into the Pi. It works great because the sensor has minimal current draw, compared to other keyboards I have used (because it doesn't have to power the keyboard, being wireless the keyboard and mouse have their own batteries.)

However, when I go to try to use NOOBS via RCA Composite (only option I have currently) the bluetooth sensor/receiver thing doesn't appear to be recognized by the Pi.

It works fine using Raspbian, but when I go to push <kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>4</kbd>, it doesn't work, so I can't use NOOBS (not a big deal, I know how to flash the image to the SD card, which gives me more control)

Any ideas on what is causing this strangeness and/or is there a way to solve it? If not, that's ok, I can just keep flashing my SD card using `dd` on Ubuntu and Win32DiskImager on Windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it may have been a battery/sync issue. I've used it since and I had to swap the batteries out and re-sync the keyboard and receiver. Granted, this was on Raspbian this time, but I believe it should work with NOOBS as well.

Sometimes the answer is the simplest thing, just sitting there waiting to facepalm you.

Comment: my bluetooth keyboard and mouse are not recognized during the NOOBS bootloader's OS selection menu. Did you try this out? Did it work?

Comment: I don't know. I think NOOBS may have issues with Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

NOOBS does not support Bluetooth either for setup or for multi-boot selection after install : https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/issues/257