# Force NOOBS 1.3 to use composite

Tags: sd-card, keyboard, composite-video, noobs

I currently only have access to composite video screens, so I can't use HDMI which makes it a royal pain to use NOOBS.

I have NOOBS 1.3 and I wanted to try dual-booting a couple different OSs, but I can't get my Pi to register my keyboard (same problem as my other un-answered problem [Using NOOBS, no keyboard](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9675/using-noobs-no-keyboard).)

I have looked at these two pages so far [NOOBS won't start](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/noobs-wont-start) and http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=56815&p=429218, but neither has been much help.

I have tried two separate keyboards, 1 that uses bluetooth and one that is wired. Both have been tried directly through the Pi and through a Plugable powered hub I have (4 port-is on the tested good list) and nothing happens with repeated <kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>4</kbd> button presses. My Pi is a 512MB Rev 2 with a Transcend 8GB Class 10 SDHC Card.

Basically I was wondering if, because my keyboards don't get NOOBS to switch to composite (work in Raspbian and NOOBS *only* via HDMI), can I manually force NOOBS 1.3 to use Composite video instead?

Sorry about the long and somewhat confusifying post, but I really want to use NOOBS, especially the Dual-booting ability of 1.3.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if you found a solution to this, but have a look at this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23915/the-composite-video-on-my-raspberry-pi-isnt-working. You mention trying the 3 and 4 keys but what about 1 and 2?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Hah, haven't touched this question in a while :) As for why I only attempted the 3rd and 4th keys, it was because I only had an composite video screen I could. I'll definitely look at that other question though! Thanks!

Comment: I saw it was an old question, but when researching my answer to the other question I came across this one and figured I would mention it.

Comment: BTW if that works for you let me know and I will mark this as a dupe and link to the other question.