# The Composite Video on my Raspberry Pi isn't working

Tags: raspbian, video, output

I run the commands

```
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o<br>
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -c "PAL 4:3"
```

and the screen changes from the default "no signal" screen to a black screen. This shows me that the Raspberry Pi is sending a signal but it is just a black screen. I am using a Raspberry Pi B+ running on raspbian. I am using the composite port. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does your Pi boot to GUI or command line? What are you using as your display? Is their anything (including a cable connected to the HDMI port?

Comment: It boots into command line, I am using a tv, there is nothing connected to the hdmi port.

Comment: Is it an led/lcd tv with overscan or an old crt? If and lcd screen do you have overscan enabled on the tv or raspiconfig? if Overscan is enabled you may not be able to see the edge of the screen and the commmand prompt is there you just can't see it. You can try booting and after a minute try typing (50 chars or so should help diagnose the problemm).

Comment: The 50 chars doesn't show up. Also, I tried getting into the desktop with startx, thinking the background would change to white (desktop background) but it didn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the noob release - previous versions would default to the composite video if nothing was connected to the HDMI port.

To correct this do the following:

1. Connect your keyboard and TV to the Pi.
2. Insert your SD card.
3. Power on the TV.
4. Power up the Pi and hold down the **SHIFT** key, until the green LED stops flickering  This will force the Pi into recovery mode).
5. If the screen is still blank try pressing the **1**, **2** **3**, **4** keys in succession (one of these will direct the output to the composite video port. You should now have the noobs menu on the screen.
6. If you haven't already done so choose an OS to install, and reboot. You may need to repeat the above to get back to this menu and continue to the next step.
7. Once you have an OS installed you will need to edit the config file (there is a link on the noobs menu) to select your TV type. Look for this line:

   **`#sdtv_mode=0`**

   remove the leading **#** and change the number at the end to one of the following:

   based on your TV type

   sdtv_mode=0    # Normal NTSC
    sdtv_mode=1    # Japanese version of NTSC – no pedestal
    sdtv_mode=2    # Normal PAL
    sdtv_mode=3    # Brazilian version of PAL – 525/60 rather than 625/50, different 
    subcarrier
8. Add the following line to the file:

   **hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1**
9. Make sure that the following line

   **hdmi_force_hotplug=1**

   is commented out (has a # at the start of the line).

10.Press the **TAB** key.

11. Click **OK**
12. Then hit the **ESC** key and let the Pi reboot.

Reference and more details can be found [here](https://bhavyanshu.me/tutorials/force-raspberry-pi-output-to-composite-video-instead-of-hdmi/03/03/2014/).

Comment: i have Raspberry pi3 , but the above steps are not working., i can see the display on HDMI but on on Composit

Comment: @N.K If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question] (http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: Thats not a new question, i am saying that the above steps are not working for me...

Comment: @N.K then start a new question and reference this question and add that this answer does not work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Edit the `config.txt` file

The `config.txt` file is located in `/boot` directory.

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Go to following line, and place # at start, if already not there:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

This will make the line like this:

```
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

**Then save the file (Ctrl+o) and exit (Ctrl+x)**

[image: RPi - Edit config.txt file in by nano]

Comment: Thank you! The question has already been answered, but this is another excellent solution!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is stumbling across a just flickering screen [not blue(no signal), not black(consistent signal)]: Double check your connection!

Just found out that Raspberry decided to not stick to commercial 3.5mm 4pin standard. Thought I can use a regular 3.5mm 4pin cable (with composite video), but u can not.

They **inverted GND and Video pin**:

```
Sleeve - Composite video (NORMALLY THIS IS GND)
Ring 2 - Ground
Ring 1 - Audio-Right
Tip - Audio-Left
```

Check out the Schematics [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99949/what-is-the-configuration-of-the-4-pole-a-v-jack-on-the-pi-4).

Comment: Which of the 3 incompatible "standards" did they not stick to?

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge, but why in the hell are there 3 different ways to design a pin mapping for such a simple cable? The one I am familiar with applies both to my Samsung tv and my wireless FPV setup. Such "problems" can be quite frustrating, especially if you try out other solutions that are doomed to be unsuccessful.