# What is the configuration of the 4-pole A/V jack on the Pi 4?

Tags: audio, pi-4

What is the configuration of the combined analogue audio and composite video 3.5mm jack on a Raspberry Pi 4?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [official schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_4b_4p0_reduced.pdf) of the Raspberry Pi 4 the configuration is:

- Sleeve - Composite video (Testpint TP24)
- Ring 2 - Ground (TP7, TP8, TP9, among others)
- Ring 1 - Audio-Right (TP23)
- Tip - Audio-Left (TP22)

[image]

([source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_4b_4p0_reduced.pdf))

Incidentally the configuration is identical to the [Pi 3 models](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/66472/19949).

---

Side note, the [preliminary Raspberry Pi 4 Model B datasheet](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711/rpi_DATA_2711_1p0_preliminary.pdf) states that:

> The analog audio output can drive 32 Ohm headphones directly.

Comment: It will not improve the quality of the audio output compared to RPi 3 models?

Comment: @Ingo, it looks pretty much the same. So I would guess it to be of similar quality.